# to_csv command in For loop not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, export-to-csv

I have 11 files in my directory that starts with 'case-export-'. For each of these files, I want to extract only 5 columns as indicated in the 'initial_columns' variable, save the results to a dataframe called 'whole_file', and write the 'whole_file' dataframe to a CSV. Because I have 11 files that matches 'case-export-' in my directory, I should have 11 CSVs generated by my script.

When I run the scripts below, I only got 1 CSV generated, and that CSV has data from the most recent file read by the For loop.

```
date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m_%d_%Y")
directory = '/Users/myname/Downloads/'
initial_columns = ['Case #','Case Subject','Created At','Labels','Body'] 

for file in (glob.glob(directory + 'case-export-*')):
    whole_file=pd.read_csv(file, usecols = initial_columns, encoding='ISO-8859-1', index_col=None, low_memory=False).replace(np.nan, 'blank', regex=True)   
    whole_file.to_csv(directory + 'case_export_trimmed_' + date + '_' + str(now.hour) + '_' + str(now.minute) + '_' + str(now.second) + '.csv')
```

I know how to get around this by adding an empty dataframe and then concatenating each 'whole_file' to the dataframe as it goes through the loop. I tried that and it worked perfectly. However, I am trying to understand why my original script that I shown above did not work as expected and why it only produced 1 CSV instead of 11. Please advise.

Comment: I think its because of the usage of time and date in the file naming. Every file name will be the same as loop completes running within `1 sec` Instead use `whole_file.to_csv(directory + 'case_export_trimmed_' + str(i)+ '.csv')` , increment `i` each time in the for loop.

Comment: An alternative is to sleep for one second between each iteration :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for this is that *now* is defined outside the for loop you have. Therefore every time you use it is is using the the same hour, minute and second in the csv file name and as a result you are overwriting the one file each time.

If you move the *now* variable definition to inside your for loop it should work:

```
for file in (glob.glob(directory + 'case-export-*')):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m_%d_%Y")
    whole_file=pd.read_csv(file, usecols = initial_columns, encoding='ISO-8859-1', index_col=None, low_memory=False).replace(np.nan, 'blank', regex=True)   
    whole_file.to_csv(directory + 'case_export_trimmed_' + date + '_' + str(now.hour) + '_' + str(now.minute) + '_' + str(now.second) + '.csv')
```

***EDIT**: Also moved *date* definition inside your for loop to get accurate date

Also I would do the following to generate the file name:

```
for file in (glob.glob(directory + 'case-export-*')):
    csv_file_name = df.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
    whole_file=pd.read_csv(file, usecols = initial_columns, encoding='ISO-8859-1', index_col=None, low_memory=False).replace(np.nan, 'blank', regex=True)   
    whole_file.to_csv(directory + 'case_export_trimmed_' + csv_file_name + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have declared the 'date' and 'now' variable outside of the loop, which means

'whole_file.to_csv(directory + 'case_export_trimmed_' + date + '*' + str(now.hour) + '*' + str(now.minute) + '_' + str(now.second) + '.csv')'

will be over writing to the same file for each of the 11 iterations, hence you will see only the 11th iteration details in the output file

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a better solution that to use date (hour/min/second), is to keep the old file name but either prefix or suffix it with trimmed:

```
for file in (glob.glob(directory + 'case-export-*')):
    whole_file = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=initial_columns, encoding='ISO-8859-1', index_col=None, low_memory=False).replace(np.nan, 'blank', regex=True)
    trimmed_file = file.replace("case-export-", "case-export-trimmed-")   
    # or trimmed_file = file.replace(".csv", "-trimmed.csv")   
    whole_file.to_csv(trimmed_file)
```

That way you have a clearer record/understanding from looking at the filenames what happened/the intention was...